# Codeigniter 3 form post show 303 status code

Tags: codeigniter

i was changed my CI version 2 to 3. But i am getting 303 see other error on form post when login. Why i am getting this error? Then what i need to change? i was try all methods but i cannot login. Can you assist me any one.

Then i tried following:

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE; or $config['compress_output'] = TRUE;
```

And This is my form submission function:

```
    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('cookie','date','form'));
    $this->load->library(array('encrypt','form_validation'));       
    $this->load->model(array('admin_model','user_model'));
    }
    public function admin_login(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_name', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('admin_password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/login.php',$this->data);
    }else {
        $name = $this->input->post('admin_name');
        $pwd = md5($this->input->post('admin_password'));
        $mode = SUBADMIN;

        if ($name == $this->config->item('admin_name')){
            $mode = ADMIN;
        }
        $condition = array('admin_name' => $name, 'admin_password' => $pwd, 'is_verified' => 'Yes', 'status' => 'Active');
        $query = $this->admin_model->get_all_details($mode,$condition);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();die;
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {

            $priv = unserialize($query->row()->privileges);
            //print_r($priv);die;
            $admindata = array(
                            'fc_session_admin_id' => $query->row()->id,
                            'fc_session_admin_name' => $query->row()->admin_name,
                            'fc_session_admin_rep_code' => $query->row()->admin_rep_code,
                            'fc_session_admin_email' => $query->row()->email,
                            'session_admin_mode' => $mode,
                            'fc_session_admin_privileges' => $priv
                        );
            $this->session->set_userdata($admindata);
            $datestring = "%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s";
            $time = time();
            $_SESSION['last_login_date']= mdate($datestring,$time);
            $newdata = array(
               'last_login_date' => mdate($datestring,$time),
               'last_login_ip' => $this->input->ip_address()
            );
            $condition = array('id' => $query->row()->id);
            $this->admin_model->update_details($mode,$newdata,$condition);
            if ($this->input->post('remember') != ''){
                $adminid = $this->encrypt->encode($query->row()->id);
                $cookie = array(
                    'name'   => 'admin_session',
                    'value'  => $adminid,
                    'expire' => 86400,
                    'secure' => FALSE
                );

                $this->input->set_cookie($cookie); 
            }
            $this->admin_model->urlAdminResponse($query->row()->email);
            $this->setErrorMessage('success','Login Success');
            redirect('admin/dashboard');

        }else {
            $this->setErrorMessage('error','Invalid Login Details');
        }
        redirect('admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the pic and add code. Snap of image is not really necessary

Comment: added my coding with construct fuction

Comment: add form code as well

Comment: is this works fine on CI 2 ?

Comment: Yes, Its works fine in CI 2

Answer (score 0):

The Session Library has been completely re-written in CodeIgniter 3 and now comes with a bunch of new features, but that also means that there are changes that you should make.

Read the
Step 6: Update your Session library usage
from
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html